# How can I install Cinnamon without the extra apps?

Tags: desktop-environments, cinnamon

I want to run Cinnamon, just not all the time. So, I would like a package that has the bare minimum of applications. I've tried to search for such a thing but all my searching has been fruitless thus far. Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to start with installation of Cinnamon [core metapackage](https://packages.ubuntu.com/focal/cinnamon-core) with essential components by

```
sudo apt-get install cinnamon-core
```

If it is very big for you, then use

```
sudo apt-get install cinnamon-core --no-install-recommends
```

instead.